# How to detect and remove invalid attributes using Javascript Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Here's a sample HTML I have (Actual HTML is pretty big & complex and I am not posting it for the sake of simplicity):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #000000;font-family:'Open Sans'">
<div class:'abc' id="cde"></div>
<div class:"abc" id="fed"></div>
<div class:abc  id="ce"></div>
<div class:"abc"><p class="content" autocomplete> I am some text which might contain attribute:"invalid value" and I must not be removed</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Goal here is to remove the invalid attributes from the HTML without disturbing the rest of the html. Obviously, the invalid attributes can be anything other than `attribute="value"`, or `attribute=value` or `attribute='value'` or even `attribute` (e.g. `<input id="abc" type="text" value="test" disabled>`) and the regex should remove it. This content cannot be loaded into DOM so please suggest regex based solutions only.

For starters, I am trying `/[a-zA-Z]+:"?'?[a-zA-Z]+"?'?/gi` but I know I am nowhere even close!

Here's [**the fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bangali/pz5w47kc/) for you to play with.

**Expected output:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #000000;font-family:'Open Sans'">
<div  id="cde"></div>
<div  id="fed"></div>
<div   id="ce"></div>
<div ><p class="content" autocomplete> I am some text which might contain attribute:"invalid value" and I must not be removed</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update 1:**

- The regex should work with any element and not just the divs. divs
  were given just for example. it should work with span etc too.
- No detection of unclosed tag is needed. We just need to remove `attribute:value`/`attribute;value`/`attribute:"value"` (basically anything other than the valid attributes supported) etc if they are inside `<element>`.

Comment: Is the `JS` regex engine a must? `PCRE` is far more advanced. Additionally: do you need to consider multiple broken attributes?

Comment: @Jan JS regex engine is needed, because it will be executing client side. Multiple broken attribute support is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though generally not advisable, you could use two expressions on the `DOM`, one to filter *potentially* elements, one to actually eradicate the attributes in question:

```js
var html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #000000;font-family:'Open Sans'">
<div class:'abc' id="cde"></div>
<div class:"abc" id="fed"></div>
<div class:abc  id="ce"></div>
<div class:"abc"><p class="content" autocomplete> I am some text which might contain attribute:"invalid value" and I must not be removed</p></div>

<!-- another one here -->
<div class:'abc defg'  id="ce"></div>

</body>
</html>`;

var cleaned = html.replace(/<(?:(?!>).)*\b\w+:['"]?\w+['"]?.*?>/g, function(match) {
    return match.replace(/\s+\w+:(?:(?:'[^']*')|(?:"[^"]*")|\w+)\s*(?!\w)/g, '');
});

console.log(cleaned);
```

---

Broken down, this says for the first expression ([**demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/3fEsJH/1)):

```
<           # <
(?:(?!>).)* # anything where > is not immediately ahead
\b\w+:      # a word boundary +1 word characters and :
['"]?       # quotes, optional
\w+         # another 1+ word characters
['"]?       # as above
.*?         # anything else lazily afterwards
>           # >
```

... and for the second (inner) one:

```
\s+\w+:          # 1+ whitespaces, 1+ word characters
(?:              # non-capturing group
    (?:'[^']*')  # '...'
    |            # or
    (?:"[^"]*")  # "..."
    |            # or
    \w+          # 1+ word characters
)
\s*(?!\w)        # 0+ whitespaces, make sure there's no 
                 # word character ahead
```

---

Note that this won't take into account sth. like `data-attribute='some weird <> characters here: """'>` or `data-key="hey, i'am \"escaped, yippeh!">`, which are both totally valid.
If you expect such input, really use a parser instead.

Comment: This solution is working so far! I will do some more testing and compare  with the other answers for speed and choose the accepted answer by tomorrow. Thanks a lot for your attempt.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function twice:

```js
var html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #000000;font-family:'Open Sans'">
<div class:'abc' id="cde"></div>
<div class:"abc" id="fed"></div>
<div class:abc  id="ce"></div>
<div class:"abc"><p class="content" autocomplete required blah=blah> I am some text which might contain attribute:"invalid value" and I must not be removed</p></div>
</body>
</html>`;

var htmlCleaned = html.replace(/(<\w+)(\s[^>]*)>+/g, function($m, $1, $2) {
  return $1 + $2.replace(/\s*?(\s?\w+(?:=(?:'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|\w+)|(?!\S)))|\s*\S+/g, '$1') + ">";
});

console.log(htmlCleaned)
```

Comment: Needs some optimizations though.

Comment: Thank you for the attempt :) I will give it a try too. I will accept this as the answer if it solves the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a task that deserves a dedicated library. In order to identify invalid attributes you need to find first the valid tags that is also not that easy and clear. E.g what needs to be done when some tag is not closed? Should the uncloseable tags like `input` be supposed to be closed? Should href be an attribute of div? Etc etc etc

This is nearly impossible with plain regexp. Even if it will be it won't cover all the cases or will be too complex = unsupportable.

Just give it out to the library that does it for you e.g. this one https://github.com/dave-kennedy/clean-html

Comment: I will update the question to reflect with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This code parses your html splits the relevant parts and checks to see whether the attributes are valid.

You could probably make it more efficient as it's looping multiple times, but this way is easier to understand in it's component parts.

That said. Don't use this code. if you can't parse your element to the DOM figure out a way, if you are in Node you can parse as xml and work with the nodes to ensure everything works correctly.

My little console app doesn't display the **autocomplete** attribute but it's there in the string.

> **this code will probably fail in a production environment!**

```js
const html = document.querySelector('#input').innerHTML

const isElement = x =>
  /^<.*>$/.test(x)

const isValidAttribute = x =>
  /^(([a-zA-Z-]+)=?((?:\"|\')[^\'\"]*(?:\"|\'))*|\w+)$/.test(x)

const similarToAttribute = x => 
  /=.*((?:\"|\').*(?:\"|\'))/.test(x)

const isOpeningOrClosingBracket = x =>
  /(^<|>$)/.test(x)

const output =
  html
  // .replace(/(\n|\r)+/gm, '') // uncomment to remove new lines
  .split(/(<[^>]+>)/) // split the elements
  .filter(x => x !== "") // remove empty elements
  .map( x => !isElement(x)
      ? x // it's not an element node, return it
      : x.split(/(<\w+|>|\s)/) // split the parts of elements
        .filter(x => x !== " " && x !== "") // remove empty elements
        .reduce((acc, x) => {
          return isOpeningOrClosingBracket(x) || isValidAttribute(x)
            ? acc.concat(x) // return valid components
            : acc // failed check, dont return the attribute
        }, [])
  )
  .map(x => Array.isArray(x) // arrays are elements
    ? x.slice(0, x.length - 1).join(' ') + x[x.length -1] // join the element string
    : x // return anything else
  )
  .join('') // join the entire array into a string

const div = document.createElement('section')
div.innerHTML = output

console.log(output)
console.log(div)

/* UNIT TESTS */
expect('string is valid element format', () => {
  assert(isElement('<div>')).equal(true)
  assert(isElement('</div>')).equal(true)
  assert(isElement('not an element')).equal(false)
})

expect('string is valid attribute format', () => {
  assert(isValidAttribute('class="thing"')).equal(true)
  assert(isValidAttribute('class:\'abc\'="thing"')).equal(false)
  assert(isValidAttribute('class:\'abc\'="thing"')).equal(false)
  assert(isValidAttribute('autocomplete')).equal(true)
})

expect('string has similar properties to an attribute', () => {
  assert(similarToAttribute('this is not an attribute')).equal(false)
  assert(similarToAttribute('class:\'abc\'="thing"')).equal(true)
  assert(similarToAttribute('class:\'abc\'="thing"')).equal(true)
})

expect('string is opening or closing tag', () => {
  assert(isOpeningOrClosingBracket('<div')).equal(true)
  assert(isOpeningOrClosingBracket('>')).equal(true)
  assert(isOpeningOrClosingBracket('class="thing"')).equal(false)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
<pre id="input">
<div class:'abc' id="cde"></div>
<div class:"abc" id="fed"></div>
<div class:abc  id="ce"></div>
<div class:"abc"><p class="content" autocomplete> I am some text which might contain attribute:"invalid value" and I must not be removed</p></div>
</pre>
```

Comment: plus 1 for your attempt. Let me try to translate it to my need and I will accept the answer if it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Use This `(?<=(div ))[a-zA-Z]+:"?'?[a-zA-Z]+"?'?`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2WWVcd/1)

[In jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pz5w47kc/1/)

Comment: From the initial look, it feels like this will only work on the divs. I need something more general that will work in any element. Please feel free update the answer :)